# Is there a way in R to compare directly the proportions of a category of a variable between two categories of a different variable?

Tags: r, comparison, proportions

I have the following dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame(T=c("I","I","C","C"),
                R=c(1,0,1,0),
                nb_times = c(33,14,42,5))
y <- data.frame(lapply(x, rep, x$nb_times))
```

I want to compare the proportions of "1" by the two categories of T.
I know I may use `prop.test` providing the number of "1" in each category of T and the total number of individuals in each category of T, but I'd rather do it directly from `y$R` and `y$T`.

Thank you,

Ángel

Comment: You mean something like `chisq.test(table(y$T, y$R))`?

Comment: Thank you, Maël. With that command, I only get the chi-squared and the p value. I'd rather have in addition the proportions in each category, the difference of proportions and the confidence interval of the difference.